# Simple count id in MySql table is taking to long

Tags: mysql, performance

I have to tables with 65.5 Million rows:
1)

```
CREATE TABLE RawData1 (
  cdasite varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  id int(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  timedate datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  type int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  status int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  branch_id int(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  branch_idString varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id,cdasite,timedate),
  KEY idx_timedate (timedate,cdasite)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

2)
Same table with partition (call it RawData2)

```
PARTITION BY RANGE ( TO_DAYS(timedate))
(PARTITION p20140101 VALUES LESS THAN (735599) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20140401 VALUES LESS THAN (735689) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 .
 .
 PARTITION p20201001 VALUES LESS THAN (738064) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION future VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE ENGINE = InnoDB);
```

I'm using the same query:

```
SELECT count(id) FROM RawData1
where timedate BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(date_sub(now(),INTERVAL 2 YEAR),'%Y-%m-01') AND now();
```

2 problems:
1. why the partitioned table runs longer then the regular table?
2. the regular table returns 36380217 in 17.094 Sec. is it normal, all R&D leaders think it is not fast enough, it need to return in ~2 Sec.

What do I need to check / do / change ? 
Is it realistic to scan 35732495 rows and retrieve 36380217 in less then 3-4 sec?

Comment: @num8er - `DATETIME` and `TIMESTAMP` are roughly equivalent in parformance.  `BTREE` is the default for indexes in MySQL.  At the end vs middle?  Not that much diff.  _Do not advocate MyISAM_; it is going away.  With 65M rows and a multi-second query, there _would_ be contention due to MyISAM's table locks!  `CHAR` is almost never better than `VARCHAR`, _including_ this case.  `CHAR` leads to bigger data, which leads to more I/O, which is slower.

Comment: @num8er - I made about 7 claims, each of which I am reasonably sure about.  Some I have not check in a long time; some I indirectly check frequently by observing slow / not-slow queries.  Which one(s) would you like to discuss?  Suggest you start a new Question; we can discuss there, plus encourage others weigh in.

Answer (score 1):

- You have found one example of why `PARTITIONing` is not a performance panacea.
- Where does `id` come from?
- How many different values are there for `cdasite`?  If thousands, not millions, build a table mapping cdasite <=> id and switch from a bulky `VARCHAR(45)` to a `MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED` (or whatever is appropriate).  This item may help the most, but perhaps not enough.
- Ditto for `status`, but probably using `TINYINT UNSIGNED`.  Or think about ENUM.  Either is 1 byte, not 4.
- The `(20)` on `INT(20)` means nothing.  You get a 4-byte integer with a limit of about 2 billion.
- Are you sure there are no duplicate `timedates`?
- `branch_id` and `branch_idString` -- this smells like a pair that needs to be in another table, leaving only the id here?
- Smaller -> faster.
- `COUNT(*)` is the same as `COUNT(id)` since `id` is `NOT NULL`.
- Do not include future partitions before they are needed; it slows things down.  (And don't use partitioning at all.)

To get that query even faster, build and maintain a Summary Table.  It would have at least a `DATE` in the `PRIMARY KEY` and at least `COUNT(*)` as a column.  Then the query would fetch from that table.  More on Summary tables: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables